# Encrypted a file with AES but can't decrypt it with OpenSSL (bad magic number)

Tags: go, encryption, openssl, aes

I have encrypted a file using this code.

```
    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte("TESTPASSWORD1234TESTPASSWORD1234"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bReader, err := os.Open("doc.docx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var iv [aes.BlockSize]byte
    stream := cipher.NewOFB(block, iv[:])

    var out bytes.Buffer

    writer := &cipher.StreamWriter{S: stream, W: &out}
    if _, err := io.Copy(writer, bReader); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if os.WriteFile("doc-encrypted.docx", out.Bytes(), 0644) != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

and when I try to decrypt it using this command

`openssl enc -in doc-encrypted.docx -out doc-decryted.docx -d -aes-256-ofb`

it gives the error `bad magic number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OpenSSL statement is missing the specification of key and IV. For decryption, the following OpenSSL statement is required:

```
openssl enc -in doc-encrypted.docx -out doc-decryted.docx -d -aes-256-ofb -K 5445535450415353574f5244313233345445535450415353574f524431323334 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

The *-K* option specifies the hex encoded key, and *-iv* specifies the hex encoded IV, s. [enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html).

With this change, the ciphertext generated with the Go code can be decrypted with the OpenSSL statement.

---

Keep in mind that the use of a static IV is insecure. Typically, a random IV is generated for each encryption. This is not secret and is usually concatenated with the ciphertext: *iv|ciphertext* so that it is available during decryption. See the documentation for [`NewOFB`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#example-NewOFB) for an example (without file I/O).

Comment: Thanks @Topaco, I modified my code in a new answer. it calculates a random IV everytime and stores the salt at the file so it won't need providing IV at the decryption phase.